# Send attachment email with php and sendgrid

Tags: php, email, curl, sendgrid

I want to send an email with Sendgrid, using cURL. This is a tool I have been using for quite some time now, and everything works perfectly fine when I want to send a simple email.

However now, I'm trying to send an attachment file along with the email. What happens is that I see the file in the email, but it's displayed with only 1KB size and it's impossible to download the file.

I was thinking that this may be a path problem. The paths I tried (assuming the Php file is at the address `mywebsite.com/file.php`) are the following :

- 'http://www.mywebsite.com/documents' (an URL)
- 'documents'
- 'documents/'
- '/documents'
- '/documents/'

I also tried to enter the URL to the platform directly into the file path parameter.

The response I obtain from Sendgrid API is `{"message":"success"}`.

I'm following [this guide](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Code_Examples/v2_Mail/php.html), here is the code:

**PHP**

```
$html = '<p>Hello StackOverflow</p>';
$fileName = 'myDocument.pdf';
$filePath = 'http://mywebsite.com/documents'

$url = 'https://api.sendgrid.com/';
$user = [MY_USER];
$pass = [MY_PASS];
$js = array(
  'sub' => array(':name' => array([MY_FIRSTNAME])),
);


$params = array(
  'api_user' => $user,
  'api_key' => $pass,
  'to' => $to,
  'subject' => $subject,
  'html' => $html,
  'from' => $from,
  'fromname' => [MY_FROMNAME],
  'x-smtpapi' => json_encode($js),
  'files['.$fileName.']' => '@'.$filePath.'/'.$fileName
);

print_r($params); // AT THAT POINT, WHAT IS PRINTED IS EXACTLY WHAT I EXPECT

$request = $url.'api/mail.send.json';

// Generate curl request
$session = curl_init($request);

// Tell curl to use HTTP POST
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);

// Tell curl that this is the body of the POST
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);

// Tell curl not to return headers, but do return the response
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
// Tell PHP not to use SSLv3 (instead opting for TLS)
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// obtain response
$response = curl_exec($session);
curl_close($session);
```

Comment: `$filePath = 'http://mywebsite.com/documents'` if that is your actual syntax, it's wrong for 2 reasons. 1) it's a URL instead of a path. 2) it's missing closure. Error reporting would have told you about it.

Comment: It's not my actual syntax. But if you look in the $param variable, you obtain @http://www.mywebsite.com/documents/myDocument.pdf, which seems correct to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution, which may not be optimal but which works at least.

Replace `'files['.$fileName.']' => '@'.$filePath.'/'.$fileName`

with `'files['.$fileName.']' => file_get_contents($filePath.'/'.$fileName)`.

I'm a bit surprised that reproducing the documentation of Sendgrid API doesn't work, but maybe there is a cleaner solution which works with it. If so, feel free to share (instead of downvoting my post for example).